# I have a trouble in the search using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem in the search using Entity Framework => ***Contains***

I have three values **First Name + Second Name + Family Name**
I want to search by first name with family name without second name
But the results do not come out right

```
Where(i => i.PatientsNoString.Contains(stringValue)).ToList();
```

Comment: *But the results do not come out right* -> Which results are you expecting, which are you getting? And what is `PatientsNoString`?

Comment: Judging by the query you are running I presume you store the FirstName+SecondName+FamilyName in a single string and you want to search only by FirstName and LastName.... For that, you could do something like i.PatientsNoString.StartsWith(FirstName)  && ...EndsWith(FamilyName) but it is awful, the better solution would be if you would have separate fields for each string in the name and a separate one for the FullName

Comment: Like "asem nasser AL_Barte" I Whent Search only use asem AL_Barte without nasser

Comment: I have one textSearch

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: No results because he can not find it    
But when I type it serially come out to me

Answer (score 0):

Decided to post this as a potential solution for you: Judging by the query you are running I presume you store the FirstName+SecondName+FamilyName in a single string and you want to search only by FirstName and LastName.... For that, you could do something like

`Where(i => i.PatientsNoString.StartsWith(FirstName) && i.PatientsNoString.EndsWith(FamilyName)).ToList();`

...but it is awful, the better solution would be if you would have separate fields for each string in the name and a separate one for the FullName

Comment: Thank you ... Incorrect if the search Only Three Value Some time I have Five value i want search in three value :(